# Is there a way to select columns using eloquent one to many relationship in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. My Database is set up as:

```
social_logins
ID |   social_id  | provider
-----------------------------
 1 |      x      | twitter  
 2 |      y      | facebook
 3 |      z      | twitter

twitter_data
ID |   social_id  | some_value | another_value
-----------------------------------------------
 1 |      x      | 100         | 600
 2 |      y      | 200         | 100
 3 |      z      | 100         | 400
```

My relationship for the social_logins model is set up as:

```
public function twitterData()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TwitterData', 'social_id', 'social_id');
}
```

In my controller I want to retrieve back the twitter_data on certain columns with the foreign key of social_id. So far I have tried:
$socialLogin->twitterData->select('some_value', 'another_value');
but I just get an error that reads:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method select does not exist.
```

If I use a `lists()` call like `$socialLogin->twitterData->lists('some_value');` for only one column I am able to get data back but how can I make it work for multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lists()` works for you (btw, it's depricated and removed in 5.3, use `pluck()` instead), then using multiple arguments should also work for you:

```
$socialLogin->twitterData->pluck('some_column', 'another_column');
```

Also, you can try to pass columns in `get()` method to get only columns you want to get:

```
$data = $socialLogin->with('twitterData')->get(['some_column', 'another_column']);
```